# Update data when component creates via store in VUE3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm new with Vue and I'm having the next issue:
I need to update some text in a header, and I want to use the store to update this text when a new component is loaded. The issue is that I'm not seeing changes reflected. My code is the next one:

// store

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pageTitle: ''
  },
mutations: {
    setPageTitle (state, title) {
      state.pageTitle = title
    }
  },
getters: {
    getPageTitle (state) {
      return state.pageTitle
    }
  }
```

// header

```
<template>
...
<li><a href="#" disabled="true" class="header-title">{{ title }}</a></li></ul>
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TheHeader',
  data () {
    return {
      title: this.$store.getters.getPageTitle
    }
  } ...
</script>
```

// another any component

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MainContainer',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Main container'
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.$store.commit('setPageTitle', this.title)
  }
}
```

Any idea why header value is not changed when a new component is mounted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doe not work because `data()` function of the header component is called only once when the component is created - at that point the `title` property is initialized with the current value of `this.$store.getters.getPageTitle`.

When the store is changed later, the change has no effect on the `title`. Instead of placing the `title` in the `data()`, create a [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties)

```js
export default {
  name: 'TheHeader',
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.$store.getters.getPageTitle
    }
  }
```

Comment: It worked adding -> computed: {
    setHeaderTitle: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.getPageTitle
    } Thanks!!